# Why would a \subfile{} call not return?

Tags: subfiles

Tex presents no errors.

## Output

```
Calling Sub2.tex.
Sub2.tex entered.
Calling Sub1.tex.
Sub1.tex entered.
Sub1.tex completed.
```

## Directory structure

```
./main.tex
./Sub2.tex
./Sub1.tex
```

## main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
Calling Sub2.tex.

\subfile{./Sub2.tex}

Sub2.tex exited into main.tex.

Calling Sub2.tex.

\subfile{./Sub1.tex}

main.tex completed.
\end{document}
```

## Sub1.tex

```
\documentclass[./main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
Sub1.tex entered.

Sub1.tex completed.
\end{document}
```

## Sub2.tex

```
\documentclass[./main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
Sub2.tex entered.

Calling Sub1.tex.

\subfile{./Sub1.tex}

Sub2.tex completed.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your directory structure implies to me, that the main file as well as both sub files are located in the same folder, but `\documentclass[./main.tex]{subfiles}` let's me assume that you let it search in a folder one ore more levels up in your directory structure (where there is no such file). Does deleting the `./` in `\documentclass[./main.tex]{subfiles}` solve your problem? Otherwise, if both subfiles are one level under your main file, try `../` instead of `./` (please note the two dots).

Comment: you say you get no errors but it is hard to test your files as you get multiple unrelated errors `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.`  please provide an error free test file, and show the log you get, so we can compare and debug.

Comment: Open `main.log` and check the version of LaTeX and subfiles. My guess is that your TeX distribution is outdated and you are using a LaTeX format predating Oktober 2020. Maybe it is also the other way around, but it is almost surely a version mismatch / outdated version problem. My log file says `LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1` and `subfiles 2020/11/14 v2.2`. So the solution is to upgrade your TeX distribution. How this has to be done depends on your distribution (MiKTeX, TeXlive, ...)

Comment: @Lukas `./main.tex` (a single dot) denotes `main.tex` in the current directory. `../main.tex` (two dots) denotes `main.tex` one level up from the current directory.